# Error while posting Purchase Packing Slip Through X++

Tags: axapta, purchase-order

I have been trying to post packing slip from code. I have tried several ways but unfortunately without success.

My code is below:

```
purchTable = PurchTable::find('PO0012555');
purchFormLetter = PurchFormLetter::construct(DocumentStatus::PackingSlip);
purchformLetter.getLast();
purchFormLetter.transDate(transDate);
numberSeq  = NumberSeq::newGetNum(PurchParameters::numRefPurchPackingSlipId()).num();
purchFormLetter.update(purchTable,
"14",// numberSeq, //this is coming out blank
transDate,
PurchUpDate::All,
AccountOrder::None,
       false,
       false);
```

When I tried to execute, I was getting this error:

Inventory is closed for physical and financial transactions until

Do you have any idea? Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to masters who tried to help me but I figured out my problem. There is no problem about my code or anywhere.

We are working on this project with another consulting company. Somehow, one of developer who works other company remarked (commented) transdate line at PurchFormLetter class without any information.

So, when I tried to set transdate value at "purchFormLetter.transDate(transDate)" line, PurchFormLetter could not able to set the value cause of remarked line.

I uncommented the line and the code worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

My guess: your `transDate` variable does not have a valid date.

Using the cross reference you see the error only occurs in the `checkOpen` method of the table `InventClosing`.
Feel free to add a breakpoint here!

The method will fail if called with a blank transaction date.

Comment: Yes, yesterday I figured out that method does not take any transdate but i am passing the transdate via class. When I post packing slip through Ax, The method took correct transdate. Is there any parameter, I forgot to set??

Comment: This should be easy to solve if you put a breakpoint in as Jan suggested.  Why is it getting inside of that if statement in the "checkopen" method?

Answer (score 0):

Are you posting to a closed period?  What is transdate?  Check (General Ledger>Setup>Periods>Periods)

Comment: Hi, I dont think it's closed because Ax can do it with same order. I think I am missing something when I called class. Can you review my code, do you see any mistake or missing line?